# get sum of the product of two columns

Tags: r

Can someone explain how my order of operations for the R fuctions below is wrong? I expected to multiply across each row then sum the result, but the answer I got was very different.

```
qqq<-data.frame(c(1,2,3),c(4,5,6))
library(dplyr)
qqq%>%sum(.[,1]*.[,2]) #returns: 53

# answer I expected: 1*4+2*5+3*6 = 32
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We can use `Reduce` to get the rowwise product and then do the `sum`

```
qqq %>%
     Reduce(`*`, .) %>%
     sum
#[1] 32
```

Or as @eipi mentioned in the comments, using `{}` can also work

```
qqq %>%
   {.[,1]*.[,2]} %>%
   sum
```

Or with `do` (from @thelatemail)

```
qqq %>% 
    do(.[1]*.[2]) %>%
    sum
```

Comment: Do you have any idea why what I tried gave such a strange answer?

Comment: In the unusual case of a data frame without "real" column names, what about `qqq %>% summarise(sum(.[,1]*.[,2]))`, which would be the "standard" dplyr syntax? If you have column names, say, v1 and v2, then `qqq %>% summarise(sum(v1*v2))`.

Comment: @Rilcon42 It is a strange result, I am not sure how it got that one, perhaps `1+ 6*4 + 5*2 + 6*3`

Comment: `qqq %>% {.[,1]*.[,2]} %>% sum` and `qqq %>% apply(., 1, prod) %>% sum` also work. I haven't used `%>%` outside of dplyr before, but maybe this is how the `magrittr` pipe is supposed to work outside of the dplyr context.

Comment: I'm stumped ... `qqq %>% sum(.[,1])` gives `27` and `qqq %>% sum(.[,2])` gives `36` - go figure. `qqq %>% do(.[1]*.[2]) %>% sum` also works okay.

Comment: And check this out: `qqq %>% prod(.[,1]*.[,2])` gives 518400, which is `prod(qqq)^2`.

Answer (score 1):

I think a brief example explains what is going on here, even if I don't know *why* it occurs in terms of the underlying code:

The entire dataset is being passed to the `sum` operation, and then this is being summed together with the expression inside the `sum` operation:

Equivalent to `sum(data.frame(1:3))` in the simplest example:

```
data.frame(1:3) %>% sum()
#[1] 6
```

Then 6 + 6:

```
data.frame(1:3) %>% sum(.[1])
#[1] 12
```

Now, below the sum of the input dataset is 12, so the result is 12 + 6:

```
data.frame(1:3,1:3) %>% sum(.[1])
#[1] 18
```

Adding both columns to the sum gives 12 + 6 + 6:

```
data.frame(1:3,1:3) %>% sum(.[1],.[2])
#[1] 24
```

And adding a multiplication gives  12 + sum(1:3 * 1:3) = 12 + 14

```
data.frame(1:3,1:3) %>% sum(.[1]*.[2])
#[1] 26
```